# How to maximize the determinant of a matrix of the form VDV^H 

Tags: computer-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, linear-algebra

Hi,

I have a matrix of the form $A=VDV^H$, 
where $V$ is a $M \times 2M$ complex matrix, $D$ is a $2M \times 2M$ diagonal real matrix, thus the dimension of $A$ is $M \times M$.

My problem is how to maximize the determinant of $A$ by choosing the diagonal $D$ (suppose the sum of diagonals of $D$ equals to $1$)?

Since the dimension of $V$ is $M \times 2M$, I don't know how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: btw: ^H means hermitian transpose

Comment: since $Det A = (Det V^H V) \prod_n D_n$, this is trivial

Comment: Not sure about that: $V^HV$ is a rank-$M$ $2M\times 2M$ matrix, so its determinant would be zero.

Comment: thank you, Federico, I stand corrected; the correct formula is 

$${\rm Det}A=\sum_{S}|{\rm Det}V_{S}|^2\prod_{k\in S}D_{kk}$$


where $S$ is a subset of $M$ indices out of $1,2,...2M$ and 
$V_S$ is an $M\times M$ matrix constructed from $V$ by 
deleting the $M$ columns that are not in $S$.

it would seem that to maximize this is in general not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve your problem numerically using [CVX](http://cvxr.com/) under Matlab:

```
% assuming we have defined v and m above
cvx_begin sdp
    variable d(2*m,2*m) diagonal
    maximize det_rootn(v*d*v')
    subject to
         d >= 0;
         trace(d)==1;
cvx_end
```